# Hide java confirm dialog in signed applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have an applet that receives an XML that serialized a JasperPrint object and print it using printservices. The applet is signed and the certificate is imported in house.

This applet is in a Web application that call it using javascript and it runs in terminals with Windows XP.

The problem is that when you use the applet always displays the prompt to run the application and users have to confirm to print.

Is there any way around this without ever having to confirm?

UPDATE:

i google the problem and i see that applet is dying (like @user3712670 says), 
there are another alternative to run java code on client pc from a web page?

i need to use it locally

Comment: This isn't really a Java question- it's more a question about the specific browser you're using.

Comment: You can reduce the security settings in Java to not show any confirmation dialogs, but this is a client side setting you can't control.

Comment: @GiantTree What security settings disable the browser's plugin confirmation dialog? Have you tried testing this yourself?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Open the *Java Control Panel* and go to *Advanced*. At least in Java 7 it was possible to disable most of the security verifications and validations so that you do not get any popups. Java 8 changed this so that you get a popup regardless how low the security settings are (low was dropped due to security concerns so medium is the lowest you can get).

Comment: @GiantTree None of those are the initial confirmation dialog that the browser displays. That's from the browser, not from Java.

Comment: i test it and is a comfirm dialog related to chrome on windows xp, in windows 7/8 show it only once

Comment: @KevinWorkman that's a settings in the specific browser. All popups I keep getting originate from Java.

Comment: @user3712670 Chrome just dropped support for applets entirely. They will no longer run at all in the latest version of chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Any settings for those confirmation dialogs are client-side, so there's nothing you can do in your code or on your server to prevent them.

You might be able to get rid of some of them by making your clients change their security settings, but this is probably not advised. And you probably can't get rid of all of them.

You can check the plugin settings for the particular browser you're running, and you can check the Java security settings from the Control Panel.

The real answer is that applets are a dying technology, and trying to make them work is a bit like plugging up the holes in a sinking ship.

Comment: if applet is dying, what can i use to run java code on client pc from a web page?

Comment: @user3712670 Nothing. You either need to convert your application to a runnable jar (or an executable), or you need to convert to JavaScript (something like GWT might be helpful for that transition). It's not a fun time for us client-side Java developers. If you're in a very restricted environment, then you might be able to get away with an applet for a few more years, but for most cases they simply aren't an option anymore.

Comment: I was at +1 very early on in reading this answer, but had to 'nod in agreement' when reading *"..applets are a dying technology, and **trying to make them work is a bit like plugging up the holes in a sinking ship."***  A very apt description.  *"what can i use to run java code on client pc from a web page?"*  [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The code will still need to be digitally signed, but JWS does not suffer from many of the problems (caused by browsers) that plague applets.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Doesn't WebStart still require the Java plugin, which means it has all of the same issues that applets do?

Comment: *"Doesn't WebStart still require the Java plugin,"*  Yes, it does. *"..which means it has all of the same issues that applets do?"*  Nope.  I'm talking about things beyond merely whether the plug-in is installed and enabled.  I'm referring more to the recent habit of browsers to add their *own* hurdles before an embedded applet is launched.  Then of course, there is *[Chrome](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)* ..  Soon Chrome won't be able to embed applets at all, but it sure will allow a JNLP link to 'launch' since it is then up to the **OS** to handle it (& totally beyond Chrome).